# Manipulate Output of wp_list_something: select menu instead of li's

Tags: functions, filters, wp-list-pages, categories, responsive

I'm working on a responsive webdesign where my navigation should swap into a select-menu when resizing the window in smaller sizes.

Is it somehow possible to add another param to functions like `wp_list_categories()` or `wp_list_pages()` so that it outputs `<option>item</option>` instead of `<li>item</li>`?

So what I wanna do is use `wp_list_pages()` and `wp_list_categories()` to ouput its default stuff in order to have a normal menu. However I also want to ouput the same pages and categories in a second `<select><option>…` navigation that is hidden by default but shown when a media-query is triggerd. Any idea how to dynamically produce this second menu?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do this the same way as `wp_list_pages()`, using `wp_dropdown_pages()`.
the args needed to retrieve the pages are the same.
for the categories, use `wp_dropdown_categories()`

Comment: In addition I wrote a plugin that outputs a wordpress nav menu from the back end as a dropdown: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menus/